# How to generate N random number with a certain constant mean, sd, sumation?

Tags: r

I wrote the following code in R for generating N random number with a certain mean, standard deviation, summation. for example,

```
x <- rnorm(n=40, mean =0.030, sd=0.007, sum=1.182)
hist(x)
mean(x)
sd(x)
sum(x)
```

but given me this error:

> Error in rnorm(n = 40, mean = 0.03, sd = 0.007, sum = 1.182) :
> unused argument (sum = 1.182)

```
> hist(x)
> mean(x)
[1] 0.05
> sd(x)
[1] 0.2180813
> sum(x)
[1] 40
```

how to write a code in R that sum of random number equal to 1.182?

Comment: The `rnorm` function does not have the ability to generate numbers with a given sum. Thus `sum = 1.182` is not a valid argument. See also: [Draw from random distribution so that sum of values is fixed](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/315109/draw-from-random-distributions-so-that-sum-of-values-is-fixed)

Comment: If the mean is `0.030` and they are 40 numbers, then the sum MUST BE `1.2` IE 40*0.03 -=1.2 So it is IMPOSSIBLE to do what you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no function to do that (it wouldn't really be random sampling if the mean or sum were exactly what you specified, right? you're pulling from a distribution with those qualities, but each pull will vary from those quantities due to sampling error), but you could force it like this. Run it once and then scale it to match the desired sum.

```
set.seed(42)

x <- rnorm(n=40, mean=0.030, sd=0.007)
sum(x)
#[1] 1.18893

x <- x * 1.182 / sum(x)
sum(x)
#[1] 1.182
```

Comment: Dear Jon, Thank you so much for your reply. It's excellent.

Comment: In case you're curious, here's a very interesting paper from a few years ago that talks about generating datasets with specific statistical summary properties, which are available as examples in the `datasaurus` R package: https://www.autodesk.com/research/publications/same-stats-different-graphs